# FB Messenger steals focus

Tags: cinnamon

I am using the Facebook Messenger app for Ubuntu and unset the popups option configuration options. However, whenever a message arrives the window grabs focus, which is, as you can imagine, rather irritating.

How do I stop this happening?

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 with cinnamon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The focus-stealing behavior of Cinnamon seems to be a matter of some debate. See the Cinnamon bug tracker:

- Issue #1727: https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/1727
- Issue #2445: https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/2445
- Issue #2640: https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/2640

At the moment there does not seem to be a solution in vanilla Cinnamon. :)

However, you may want to use the [hack](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/1727#issuecomment-27872987) proposed by user **ac000** in issue #1727:

Comment out the line

`window.activate(global.get_current_time());`

in the function

`_onWindowDemandsAttention : function(display, window)`

in the file `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/windowAttentionHandler.js`. Note however, that this will prevent *any* windows from stealing focus when they require your attention. Also, this file will get overwritten each time you upgrade Cinnamon, so you may have to re-apply the hack every so often.

Comment: Thanks, I used the hack. I can't think of a situation where I have wanted a window to grab focus. I guess I will find out if this is inconvenient soon enough. 

Happy Holidays, Malte.

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy holidays to you too! :)